# Clear reactJs textarea after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea, reactjs

I have the following form component in a skylight dialog, after submit, if the dialog is reopened containing the form, it contains the previous submitted value. Can anyone please tell me how to stop this and clear the textarea value everytime the dialog is opened?

Here is my component:

```
var AddNoteForm = React.createClass({


componentDidMount: function() {

        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.notes).value = "";
},
handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var notes = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.notes).value;

    var details = {
        studentId: this.props.studentId,
        schoolId: this.props.schoolId,
        notes: notes
    };

    this.props.onSubmit(details);
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <form className="pure-form pure-form-aligned"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="pure-control-group">
                <label htmlFor="notes">Note</label>
                <textarea ref="notes" id="notes" placeholder="Note..." >
                </textarea>

            </div>
            <div className="pure-controls">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
});

module.exports = AddNoteForm;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically your form is not getting unmounted. So writing the code in componentDidMount will not make sense. So the quick fix for your problem would be to clear the textarea box after you read the value in handle submit method

```
handleSubmit: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var notes = this.refs.notes;

  var details = {
    studentId: this.props.studentId,
    schoolId: this.props.schoolId,
    notes: notes.value
  };

  notes.value = ""; // Unset the value
  this.props.onSubmit(details);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that but the value remains in the dialog, any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

so if some one stuck in this problem ,
I was using uncontrolled component and it is somehow complex to clear it,
I just change to controlled one and then got it :)

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
<textarea value={this.state.text} onChange={ e => this.handleChange(e) } />
<button>Submit Comment</button>
</form>
```

very important to prevent default

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();    
  this.setState({ text: '' });
  };
```